# how to use Flow to check the `import` module?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

---

I am learning `Flow` with react, when I import some modules, flow can't find the module.

```
import axios from "axios"; //requied module not found

export const fetchPopularRepos = (lang: string) => {
      var encodedURI = window.encodeURI(  // flow not covered
        "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>1 + language:" +
          lang +
          "&sort=stars&order=desc&type=Repositories"
      );
      return axios.get(encodedURI).then(response => response.data.items);
    };

//flow not covered
 export function getProfile(username: string) {
      return axios
        .get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}${params}`)
        .then(user => user.data);
    }
```

- how to set to not checking the modules
- how can I cover the `window.encodeURI` and `axios`

Answer (score 0):

[check this site out](https://dsslimshaddy.github.io/flowignore/) . write the package names you need and add the first regex on the ignore. its a hack ;)

so in your case you need to ignore it on flowconfig

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/[^a].*
```